# How To Integrate SOLR With Enterprise Edition?

Tags: magento-enterprise, solr, enterprise-1.14

I have a enterprise edition I want to activate solr search engine in that I have configured it and ajax result are showing in search but in solr admin panel I didn't get any result bu fetching query and analysis :

[image]

No result in Solr search 
[image]

How to connect with solr? And when I activate solr default engine no product shown in frontend. Please tell me how to configure it.

Comment: **solr-4.10.4**

Comment: **enterprise-1.14.2.0**

Comment: Check this: https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-install-apache-solr-for-magento-store/ Setting port is crucial sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version solr-4.10.4 configured with community edition but not With enterprise edition ? Install solr to your root folder : [download](http://apache.mirrors.lucidnetworks.net/lucene/solr/4.10.4/solr-4.10.4-src.tgz)

From magento Connect install the solr solarium extension then go to your

```
Root folder >> app >> code >> community >> JeroenVermeulen >> Solarium >> docs And copy schem.xml and solrconfig.xml .
```

Copy both the file and paste to your solr folder :

```
Solr-4.10.4 >> example >> solr >> collection1
```

paste it here you are done here with solr now start solr by using cmd or terminal by using given command

```
. cd solr/example/ rahul@rahul:/opt/solr/example$ java -jar start.jar
```

now your solr is started do not close the terminal window Now go to you magento admin panel

```
 system >> configuration >> catalog >> solarium search:
```

General setting : enabled it Solr server : Test your connection if success then you can start solr search For solr admin : localhost:8983 Please refer this link for brief description : [LINK](https://groovyrb.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/solr-configuration-with-magento/)

Comment: How can I check on Solr admin that its searching products correctly?

Answer (score 2):

That dashboard looks like a newer version, AFAIK Magento only officially supports up to Solr 3.6.2

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog post about installing Solr with Magento EE which will help you with it's integration. As andrewkett said, You can install Solr 3.6.2, with which recent Magento Enterprise editions are compatible https://amitshree.wordpress.com/2014/10/26/installing-solr-search-in-magento-enterprise-edition/